# Why does this switch compile when it's not exhaustive?

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I have this `Result` enum:

```
public enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

And wanted to implement `CustomStringConvertible`, so I did. (Don't poke holes in this, it's been simplified for this question :):

```
extension Result: CustomStringConvertible {

    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .success(let value as CustomStringConvertible):
            return "Result.success(\(value.description))"
        case .success(let value):
            return "Result.success(\(value))"
        case .failure(let error as CustomStringConvertible):
            return "Result.failure(\(error.description))"
        }
    }
}
```

Running this in a Playground it complies absolutely fine. However, it errors out on the final `r.description`. (The same runtime failure happens in my app, so it's nothing to do with being in a playground.)

```
var r: Result<String> = .success("hello")
r.description

r = .failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
r.description

struct MyError: Error { }
r = .failure(MyError())
r.description
```

After a lot of head scratching and setting through code I found that it's because `MyError` doesn't implement CustomStringConvertible, so no cases in the switch match. I assume this means that garbage is returned from that method.

So, does anyone know why this switch compiles?

---

**EDIT**

After fixing this in the playground by adding a final case like this:

```
case .failure(let error):
    return "Result.failure(\(error))"
```

it works. However, when I add this back into my app the compiler has the audacity to issue a warning: `warning: case is already handled by previous patterns; consider removing it` - is this a bug in Swift (unlikely) or have I misunderstood the relationship between `Error` and `CustomStringconvertible` (more likely)?

Comment: Defining the 3rd case as `case .failure(let error as NSError):` makes it work in all cases (and no warnings), but I do not have a full explanation.

Comment: It *seems* that the compiler thinks that an `Error` always adopts `CustomStringConvertible`, but it does so only when bridged to `NSError`.

Comment: OK, thats's what I'd assumed, but just wanted to make sure I wasn't going totally mad!

Comment: `case .failure(let error): return "Result.failure(\((error as CustomStringConvertible).description))"` works as well ...

Comment: I've raised a bug here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7001 to see what they make of it.

Comment: Looking at the output when I try casting inside the string, is it doing NSError things behind the scenes? I think I'm realising I don't know enough about how Error works . .  .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you import `Foundation` in the file you define the `Result` type. Well, this has the (sometimes) unwanted effect of the compiler bridging Swift values to Objective-C compatible objects, and this is what it happens in your case.

Removing the `import Foundation` clause will result in your switch no longer compiling due to not being exhaustive. I suspect that the `Foundation` import bridges the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol from the `.failure` case into some Objective-C value, but an improper one, that crashes the app.

Comment: I've removed `import Foundation` from my file and I still get the same error. Is this something Xcode is adding for me - are you working inside Xcode or doing command line things (I don't know enough about how Foundation etc gets imported)

Comment: @deanWombourne it might be that the `Foundation` import comes from files that are compiled before the `Result` one. You can try moving that file into a dedicated library and see if that fixes the problem. Or, you could just add the 4th enum case :)

Comment: I've already spent 4 hours I didn't have on finding this, so I've raised a bug and written the 4th case. Reality and deadlines are conspiring against me! (bug is here: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7001)